# Call a static function from a class instance in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

how can I call a static function from an instantiated class variable?

Example:

```js
class Foo {
  static Bar() {
    console.log("Bar");
  }
}

let i = new Foo();

i.Bar() // Not working

// Something like this?
i.toClass().Bar();
```

Comment: Why not use `Foo.Bar()`?

Answer (score 0):

As Bar is static, so you call it simply with class name Foo

```
Foo.Bar();
```